# SoapUI request response content externalize

Tags: soapui

I need to set request/response content of any test request dynemically from external xml folder(requestfolder, responsefolder) using groovy. Also there is a mockservice running. I need this kind of implementation because there are number of mockservices and also multiple responses within it. So I want to externalize them and call them dynemically
through groovy

Is anyone have done this before?

AMIT

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have multiple request XMLs? Is it because you have different data in them? In that case i suggest you put the data in an excel or csv and based on the data in the data source generate the xml.

If you are using the pro version then you should be able to read the xml files from your local drive and present that as the response from the mock service.

All this can be done using groovy.